# Stop scrolling at a certain point in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need to create smooth scroll to `ID`s using jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
  var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
      var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
      $root.animate({
          scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      }, 500, function () {
          window.location.hash = href;
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Its  working fine for me. But one thing, I need to stop scrolling at a certain point of the top of the page. For example `200px` from the top.

At this stage its always scrolling to top of the page.

Can anybody tell me how to modify this code? 
Thank you.

Comment: can you place your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

by adding this:

```
(($(href).offset().top >= 200 ) ? $(href).offset().top : 200)
```

It checks how far the element is away from the top, if its more than 200px it will scroll to it else it will scroll to 200px from the top

here is the new code:

```
  var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
      var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
      $root.animate({
          scrollTop: (($(href).offset().top >= 200 ) ? $(href).offset().top : 200)
      }, 500, function () {
          window.location.hash = href;
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: Rickdep, I just checked you code. But it still scroll to top of my page.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you have something like header with height for example `200px` and `position:fixed` to top. And your current script is scrolling too high, hiding hash title under the header.

So if this correct you just need to subtract header height from `$(href).offset().top` (e.g. `scrollTop: $(href).offset().top-200`)

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2zxnauc/)

Comment: I checked it, but it doesn't work for me. I always scrolling to top when click on a link.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `scrollTop: $(href).offset().top` to `scrollTop: $("body").offset().top + 200`

This will take the really top position (0) and then you can manipulate your scrolling for position you need